# exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I run this code I get this error in VB

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

This the code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim A(0 To 11) As Integer
    Dim B(0 To 11) As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim CountB As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Console.Write("Enter 11 A and B inputs: " + vbNewLine)
    For Count = 0 To 11
        Console.Write("A : ")
        A(Count) = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.Write("B : ")

        B(Count) = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write(vbNewLine)
    Next
    For Count = 0 To 11
        total = A(Count) * B(CountB)
    Next
    Console.Write(vbNewLine)
    For Count = 0 To 11
        Console.Write("A({0:g}) * B({1:g}) = {3:g} ", A(Count), B(CountB), total & vbNewLine)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub


End Module
```

This is where it highlights the error:

```
Console.Write("A({0:g}) * B({1:g}) = {3:g} ", A(Count), B(CountB), total & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: vba <> vb.script, which is it? vba is for apps like excel and word.  vb.sript is for visual studios.

Comment: vb.script Its a console application Can you Help

Comment: If this is VBScript, your `Dim` statements won't work - AFAIK VBScript doesn't permit typed variables.  Are you sure this isn't VB.Net?

Comment: It is a VB.net I think I am using Visual basic 2012 console application

Comment: It's many years since I used VB.Net (assuming this **is** VB.Net) but does `{3:g}` accept a String such as `total & vbNewLine`, or does it expect a numeric value?

Comment: This is VB.Net, VBScript doesn't has `console.write`-  Why didn't you looked at the error class [System.FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx).. Hint: what is third index number if starts at zero?

Comment: If it is VB.Net, please update your tag.  And the [visual-studio-2012] tag says "Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio -- not just a coding issue." so I doubt if that tag is appropriate either.  (If you want people to see your question who are able to answer the question, it's best to assign appropriate tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what causes the exception:

```
Console.Write("A({0:g}) * B({1:g}) = {3:g} ", A(Count), B(CountB), total & vbNewLine)
```

Should be:

```
Console.Write("A({0:g}) * B({1:g}) = {2:g} ", A(Count), B(CountB), total & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: Ah, well spotted!